# Get count of rows for a repository query before the actual call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Repository` class implementing `PagingAndSortingRepository`. 
There is a method as below which returns paginated results.

```
@Query("SELECT dt FROM Data dt JOIN dt.categories dc WHERE dt.service in (:services) AND dc.id = :cid")
    public List<Data> findForCategoryAndServices(@Param("cid")String cid, @Param("services")Set<Service> services, Pageable page);
```

I need a cumulative count of all the data which can help depict pagination at UI. Is there some method out of the box for this?

Or should I make an explicit count query for the above query which is but obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a `Page<Data>` rather than a `List<Data>`, and Spring-data will execute the count query for you, by deriving it from the actual query.

If it can't, or if you have a better count query, you can specify it using the `countQuery` annotation parameter.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. Perhaps you refer to `getTotalElements()` in the `Page` interface if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Yes. That's what will contain the result of the count query.